# 2-way data-binding for HashMap elements

Tags: android, android-databinding

I have a HashMap in my POJO like this:

```
class MyPojo extends BaseObservable {
    HashMap<String, Friend> friends;

    @Bindable
    public HashMap<String, Friend> getFriends(){
        return friends;
    }

    public void setFriends(HashMap<String,Friend> newFriends){
        friends=newFriends;
        notifyPropertyChanged(BR.friends);
    }

}
```

This can trigger rebinding of views when I change the elements of friends with new elements. But, If I only add and remove elements in the `friends` variable, this does not trigger any changes in the views.

I know it is not triggered because friends is a hashmap and its pointer doesn't changes. I never call `setFriends` after the initial call so it will not trigger rebinding of views.

How can I trigger changes when the internal `Friend` changes or element added or removed from the friends list?

Comment: are you using this data for listview or gridview??

Comment: @Chandra For list. But, Its not RecyclerView or ListView.

Comment: if you are using listview or gridview then you can use adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); for it.

Comment: No.. I know that one..

Comment: what type of view you are using to view the data??

Comment: I inflate custom views based on the data received from the server. And user can check/uncheck an item, which should disable on screen and removed from hashmap. Its a super-complex form with too many edittexts and lists.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123133/discussion-between-chandra-and-kirtan403).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use add remove function for the model and call `notifyPropertyChanged()` to notify the change of the view.

```
class MyPojo extends BaseObservable {
HashMap<String, Friend> friends;

@Bindable
public HashMap<String, Friend> getFriends(){
    return friends;
}

public void setFriends(HashMap<String,Friend> newFriends){
    friends=newFriends;
    notifyPropertyChanged(BR.friends);
}

public void add(String str,Friend friend)
{
    friends.put(str,friend);
    notifyPropertyChanged(BR.friends);
}

public void remove(String str,Friend friend)
{
    friends.remove(str,friend);
    notifyPropertyChanged(BR.friends);
}
}
```

Comment: Simple and elegant!  I liked it! However, I found that you can also directly call `notifyPropertyChanged` from MyPojo's instance. Or you can set up an extra method which can call notifyPropertyChanged on multiple variables.